# Multiply percentages in Sass

Tags: variables, math, sass

How do I multiply two percentages together in Sass, in a sensible way?

For example, consider the following declarations:

```
$num1: 50%;
$num2: 25%;
$num3: $num2 * $num1;
```

Here, `num3` breaks. What expression can I write to have `num3` defined as `12.5%`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out; first you need to convert one of the percentages to a decimal. Here's how it's done:

```
$num1: 50%;
$num2: 25%;
$num3: ($num2/100%) * $num1;
```