# sass multiplication Operators not working with %

Tags: sass

I have issue Operators % in Sass when i use a for loop

```
@for $i from 1 to 10 {
  .colu-md-#{$i}{
    width: #{$i} * 10%;
  }
}
```

But it results into:

> Error: Undefined operation "1 * 10%".

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiply percentages in Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833270/multiply-percentages-in-sass)

Comment: thank you. I finished processing. it's wrong syntax =>> width: $i * 10%;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got syntax error. code is attached below. Hope this will be helpful for you

```
@for $i from 1 to 10 {
  .colu-md-#{$i}{
    width: #{$i * 10%};
  }
}
```